# 10 (count 'em) x-caja-desktop windows open upon Mint 16 login, often

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login, caja

Running Linux Mint 16 Petra on an HP Mini 1101, up-to-date.  Since install, sometimes when I log in (as either of two users) exactly ten (at least the last two times, I counted) x-caja-desktop (file browsers pointed at the Desktop folder) windows will open right after logging in.  Happens right after a cold boot or a logout-then-login-as-other-user, doesn't make a difference.  But doesn't always happen.  Why is this intermittent, and more importantly, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i tried and succeded,

1. Logoff.
2. Enter in guest mode
3. Delete caja folder from .cache folder in your home/
4. Restart again

OR

1. crtl+alt+t==> terminal
2. delete the same via terminal command `sudo rm -r <cajafolder>`
3. Restart again

you can also try deleting the .cache folder entirely via any of those two methods. Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had this happen in a long time, but I'm not sure what fixed it.  I'm glad you posted in case of a regression!  Are you on Mint 17 now?  That might have done it...

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a solution [here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-session-manager/issues/19#issuecomment-12765981).

However, it didn't work.  I just had it happen again.

Comment: If the solution doesn't work, why publish it as an answer?

Comment: @fixer1234 it's not the right answer, but it's an answer--someone else will just post it anyway.